# Vue doesn't react to HTML Object Property Changes

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

I would like to use `v-if` to have elements react to the ["paused" property](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/av_prop_paused.asp) of an [Audio element](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_av_dom.asp).

Upon selecting a valid wav file and clicking play, the "Play" button should turn into a "Pause" button. When the audio is finished playing, the "Play" button should reappear. Unfortunately, when the "Play" button is clicked, it doesn't change to a "Pause" button.

Is there a way to make Vue react to the "paused" property?

```
<div id="app">
  <input 
    type="file"
    accept="audio/wav"
    @change="setFile($event)"
  />
  <button
    v-if="audio.paused"
    @click="audio.play()"
  >Play</button>
  <button
    v-else
    @click="audio.pause()"
  >Pause</button>
</div>
```

```
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    return {
      file: File,
      audio: Audio
    };
  },
  watch: {
    file() {
      this.initializeAudioPlayer();
    }
  },
  methods: {
    setFile($event) {
      this.file = $event.target.files[0];
    },
    initializeAudioPlayer() {
      this.audio = new Audio()
      if (this.file != null) {
        this.audio.src = URL.createObjectURL(this.file);
      }
    }
  },
});
```

Here is the [JSFiddle for the above code](https://jsfiddle.net/ehahn307/dpeqw6rx/33/).

Comment: You have to add one data property to maintain current running state for the audio. [HtmlMediaElement.paused](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement/paused) is read only, so `Vue.set` will be useless.

Comment: That's what I'm currently doing. I was hoping to get things a bit cleaner though. Thanks for mentioning.